# What are the practical benefits of being a Muslim?

Tags: secular

***[The answer is critical for me and really I need help]***

For years I almost had Mumin/Believer's signs cited in Quran. But after a while I found out that this makes  life for me hard and, for others easy. I had to decide if I can do *X* or *Y*. I have to had stress to keep God satisfied. I had to force myself to worship and to avoid sins. I had to keep in my mind that I'm Muslim for the whole of the day and night. I had to force myself to do what my mind did not understand. Specially I always had to be careful about prayer times to not miss a prayer!

Nowadays, I know more about ***liberal*** and **secular** societies and people. They're free. They have not to think if something is a sin or not. They can do what they think is right and the law will protect them. As a result they're more happy than we are because they feel the free. They have not to think if they can have this music or how they should pray in Alaska or Norway when the length of the day time is abnormally long. They can try things and learn.

I know there are problems with them too. But I mean **on average**. On average they are better than us in Science, Technology, Societies, Successfulness and even Morality! They're more serious to doing their job well than us, on average.

My question is, **when a non-Muslim who does not accept Islam, can be good, successful and a university scientist, why should I force myself to be a Muslim?** I know the Quran's provided advantages and punishments but all of them are after death. A death after a hard life. **What's the problem with non-Muslim guys in Liberal or Secular societies who are good and respectful that I should force myself to be a Muslim?** and **so, with what motivation should I be a Muslim and keep this until my death?!!**

Please help!

Comment: I guess the point here is, Islam is not what Muslims do. So you could at worst assume that they're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Gigili, this is the result when as I cited it makes life hard for the follower and get the freedom of him/her!

Comment: Man, you are a good Muslim, Otherwise you wouldn't even care to ask. I hope you will have a nice successful life before and after death :)

Comment: *They have not to think if something is a sin or not.* I certainly don't worry about "sin", but I do put a fair bit of time (not enough, probably) into thinking about ethics. How does my lifestyle, the way I spend my time, the way I spend my money, the way I make my money affect the world as a whole? And how do my interpersonal reactions affect those around me? Should I boycott this company or that company which has engaged in unethical business practices? This stuff is *complicated*. (But I do get to think for myself, and to learn from others.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

God is *Ar-Rahman* (the Gracious) and *Ar-Razaq* (the Provider) to all mankind, Muslim and non-Muslim alike.  Even those who
do not believe in Him benefit from His grace and His blessings, for everything that happens in
this world only happens according to God's will.

> <sup>[4:79](http://quran.com/4/79)</sup> ***What comes to you of good is from
>   Allah, but what comes to you of evil, [O man], is from yourself.***...

God grants success and power to whosoever He chooses in this world; I will not try
to explain (or even to understand) His wisdom, we can know nothing of such
matters except what He has revealed to us already.  The fundamental difference
between being a Muslim who has (or has not) receieved such rewards, compared to a
liberal secular non-Muslim who has (or has not) received the same, is that we know that
in this world is but the smallest portion of God's bounty.

> [[Muslim 39:6740](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/267400)] *When a non-believer does
>   good he is made to taste its reward in this world. And so far as the believer is
>   concerned, Allah stores (the reward) of his virtues for the Hereafter and
>   provides him sustenance in accordance with his obedience to Him.*

So to answer the crux of your question, the practical worldly advantages to being a Muslim is the knowledge that things will get much better.

---

Of course, just knowing that you'll be rewarded in the afterlife doesn't really help when you're stuck in this world.  Muslims are surrounded by trials and temptations everywhere, and it is easy to be lured by the prospect of easy worldly success.  Fortunately for us, God has made His religion easy to follow ([Qur'an 22:78](http://quran.com/22/78)).

So I wonder why you claim to have stress trying to keep God satisfied.  Do you worry about when to pray, when God is *as-Sami`* and able to hear you wherever you are?  Do you force yourself to avoid every minor sin, when God is *al-Ghaffar* and able to forgive you when you transgress unintentionally?  Do you struggle not to forget you're Muslim, when God is *al-Hadi* and best able to guide you down the straight path?

Do you drive yourself from belief and into disbelief by making the religion hard on yourself, and expect to keep God satisfied?

Obey what God has commanded, and avoid what He has prohibited, but know that He does not burden anybody beyond what he is capable of bearing ([Qur'an 7:42](http://quran.com/7/42)).  And in the end He is the one who will be the final judge over you.

As for those times when you do feel overburdened to the point of losing faith, I will close with this nugget of wisdom (attributed to the prophet Jesus in the previous scriptures):

> *No servant can serve two masters. Either you will hate the one and love the
>   other, or you will be devoted to the one and despise the other.*

And when you find yourself despising God, you should just consider to yourself: *Who, or what, am I actually devoting myself to?*

Comment: I love sentences which are talking about God's kindness and gracious. Another time http://quran.com/7/42 waked up something in mine; while I have been read it severally before! This feel which is doing something in my heart is the only reason or motivation of correctness of Islam. Yes, I'll try and I wont devote myself to something except God and I hope, I hope things will be much better and the graceful God will not charge except my capacity. I know a scientist who Quran has effect on, is really much better than one who Quran does not effect at all and I want to be the first not second!tnxGld

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand the concept here.

**Nobody is forcing you to follow the ways of Islam.** As a Muslim, I believe that all of it's teachings are true, and that it is the only way to Heaven. Also, in my belief, those who don't believe and follow Islam will end up in Hell. *But this is my belief.*

> لَكُمْ دِينُكُمْ وَلِيَ دِينِ
>
> For you is your religion, and for me is my religion. [109:6]

Now to answer your question. You are basically asking why you should keep your beliefs as a Muslim, if there is no reward in this world. What you don't understand is *this world is a test.* Allah is testing us. He sent us to Earth to see if we would follow him and worship him. You are not, in my eyes, passing his test, but only He knows.

Allah is not forcing you to believe:

> إِنَّ الَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا سَوَاءٌ عَلَيْهِمْ أَأَنذَرْتَهُمْ أَمْ لَمْ تُنذِرْهُمْ لَا يُؤْمِنُونَ
>
> Indeed, those who disbelieve - it is all the same for them whether you warn them or do not warn them - they will not believe. [2:6]

He has sent warnings, and has sent you his Messengers. There is no other way to be rewarded in the Afterlife. Remember this. It is your only motivation.

Comment: You, I and we know that a lot of people will fail this test now and in fauture and will be in your cited Hill forever! it's not a fair test!

Comment: @YasserZamani Why is this not fair? Allah is asking you to struggle in this life to have everything in Heaven.

Comment: because there are a lot of people are in Hill when you're in Heaven just because they don't pray or fast!

Comment: @YasserZamani I really don't see the point you are trying to make here. So are you saying an Atheist who devotes his life to helping others should be allowed to go to Heaven, even though it is the home of God and he doesn't believe in God?

Comment: I just try to say that there are respectful successfull e.g. scientist now, past and feauture that dont pray and fast. Will they be in Hill? if so, it's not understandable and rational for me; if not, why I should pray and fast while one who don't can go to Heaven!

Comment: @YasserZamani Can you please clarify what you are saying.

Comment: @YasserZamani Trust me if you saved the whole mankind but you do not believe in god, Then HILL is the only destination... They can be happy and successful for 100 years?? but as a Muslim you can be happy forever in heaven.

Comment: I haven't read much of Islamic history, but i think that we have seen practical advantages of being  Muslim in Islamic Golden Age. Be it Science, Art or trade, Muslims were respected (and were considered as an authority in these fields) every where.

Comment: @MohammadYaseen But today, honestly, Muslims in general are not respected. They are the enemies to people who don't know better.

Comment: @Dynamic Yes, but aren't there reasons for that?

Comment: @MohammadYaseen I'm not getting into this conversation here. All I'm going to say is there are ignorant people in the world.

Answer (score 1):

> And do not exchange the covenant of Allah for a small price. Indeed,
>   what is with Allah is best for you, if only you could know. Surat An-Naĥl [16:95]

That is all I gotta say. This world and everything within it is nothing compared to the hereafter. A Muslim should try to have a good life in this world but not in exchange of the hereafter. Just give it a thought.

> And this worldly life is not but diversion and amusement. And indeed,
>   the home of the Hereafter - that is the [eternal] life, if only they
>   knew. Surat Al-`Ankabut [29:64]

This world is insignificant, trivial compared to the Hereafter. It will eventually cease and come to end, be it a life with trials or amusement. Without Faith, even your good deeds are void [talking of morality of disbelievers].

Read Qur'an, soften your heart - You will find your answers and motivation.

Comment: @Ershad, I was what you want for several years; My heart was softed by Qur'an and I understand that Qur'an is really effective. I already know that God exists but I expect from a merciful God to allow me to make my decision but rescue me after, if needed. I'll do it for who I love. am I more merciful than God or God does not love us? I would like to live freely and nobody has rights to throw me to Hill. Thanks to God that created me but I want to be able to decide and maybe change my decision after death if needed. why we're forced to death?!!!

Answer (score 1):

Allah (c.c) says ([9-11](http://quran.com/9/111) Sahih International)

> Indeed, Allah has purchased from the believers their lives and their
>   properties [in exchange] for that they will have Paradise. They fight
>   in the cause of Allah , so they kill and are killed. [It is] a true
>   promise [binding] upon Him in the Torah and the Gospel and the Qur'an.
>   And who is truer to his covenant than Allah ? So rejoice in your
>   transaction which you have contracted. And it is that which is the
>   great attainment.

According to this ayah, believers gave up their life and wealth in exchange for paradise. When one does ibadah, one gives their precious life and when one does charity one gives their precious wealth. Allah says you will get paradise in exchange for this. If Allah promised rewards in this world, Prophet (pbuh) would have most carefree and wealthy life. But he (pbuh) didn't. So, one shouldn't expect anything in this world in exchange for one's ibadah and takwa.

On the other hand, there are some ancillary benefits for believing. First of all, it gaves meaning and purpose to life. That is indeed great relief for a believer. Also, knowing that you are not a randomly initialized meatball, alone in a huge universe also increases your spiritual wellness, and gives you a positive view about yourself. Moreover, believing in hereafter, changes the otherwise horrifying fact of death, into something ordinary.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I do not have much to say regarding this, But the comparison you are making is not fair. you are comparing oranges with apples.. That is wrong.

You said "*LIBERAL and SECULAR societies and guys*" are having a nice successful respectful life.. and Muslims do not. You also said Muslims go to heaven after they die... well you are comparing their life which will last 100 years maximum (allah A'alam) with your after life in heaven which will last **FOREVER**? so it is not a fair comparison!! it is actually in our favor. let them have the *100* respectful successful years.. and you get the **ENDLESS** years after that in heaven. And heaven in fact is something much better than *successful and respectful*, something that not you nor me nor any human can imagine..

Answer (score 0):

**I think one of the main issues for people coming to terms with Islam is that the world, and all of Allah's creation is at times too big to perceive, let alone understand.**

#### Possessions

Put one must keep in mind that this isn't your earth, with your possessions, your materials, your money, your knowledge, your anything. It all belongs to Allah, and He has only lent these things to us, from His infinite mercy.

I find this in itself more freeing than any liberal, secular life I could lead:

> *“I am satisfied with Allah as My Lord, with Islam as my religion and with Muhammad as my Prophet”.*                                                                            (Abu Dawud, Book 41, Number 5054)

Note the word satisfied, meaning that those three things are sufficient. Let go of whatever is in the way of worshipping Allah. You mention you stress out about missing prayer times, and sinning. Those things are easy to remedy, what is difficult is not missing prayer times *and partaking in this worldly life*. Keeping in mind you are Muslim is not hard, *so long as nothing else takes over your mind*. Free your self from ideas of nationality, race and other prejudices. You are a Muslim *first* and *foremost*.

This is true regardless of your faith, that the prosperous non-muslims you speak of who are 'happy' owe their happiness, possessions and life to Allah. And they do not even show respect to Allah, when He created mankind only to worship him?

#### Worship and afterlife

> On the Day when those who disbelieved are exposed to the Fire: *"You dissipated the good things you had in your worldly life and enjoyed yourself in it. **So today you are being repaid with the punishment of humiliation for being arrogant in the Earth without any right and for being deviators.**"* (Surat al-Ahqaf: 20)

The afterlife as well is often seen as compensation or consolation for having died, rather than a reward for making it through this life. **Can you imagine a marathon runner, crossing the finish line in first place and having to be consoled that the race is over?** No! He would be rewarded for his efforts, though they left him tired, and broken.

It's as though some people thing that in dying you have been wronged, and your life has been stolen away from you. This is backwards, as the goal of a muslim is towards Jannah (paradise), regardless of the Dunyah (worldly life). So put Jannah first.

Let go of this life, and submit to Allah and his teachings and insha Allah he will make it easy for you.

Comment: I just wanted to add that whilst I in no way feel this is a good enough answer to convey my feelings over why a Muslim life is happier and more prosperous, I am a revert to Islam, and I used to be one of those 'liberal and secular' guys. But I gave it up for Allah, and now I have found peace, alhamduillah